# Is there any way to convert camel-cased names to use underscores in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

For instance, I want to convert "CamelCasedName" to "camel_cased_name".  Is there a way to do this in emacs?

Comment: The short answer to any question of the form "Is there any way to _____ in emacs?" is Always "YES"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This small bit of code from [this page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CamelCase), with a wrapper function and an underscore replacing the hyphen with an underscore, could easily be turned into a command to do that. (Check that it treats leading caps to suit you):

> Sample EmacsLisp code to un-CamelCase  a string (from http://www.friendsnippets.com/snippet/101/):

```
(defun un-camelcase-string (s &optional sep start)
  "Convert CamelCase string S to lower case with word separator SEP.
Default for SEP is a hyphen \"-\".

If third argument START is non-nil, convert words after that
index in STRING."
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    (while (string-match "[A-Z]" s (or start 1))
      (setq s (replace-match (concat (or sep "-") 
                                             (downcase (match-string 0 s))) 
                                     t nil s)))
    (downcase s)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Emacs has [glasses-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Glasses.html) which displays camelcase names with underscores in between. (See also http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GlassesMode).

If you want to actually change the text of the file `M-x query-replace-regexp` is probably suitable.

Answer (score 3):

Moritz Bunkus wrote an [elisp function](https://www.bunkus.org/blog/2009/12/switching-identifier-naming-style-between-camel-case-and-c-style-in-emacs/) to toggle between CamelCase and c_style

Comment: the package `string-inflection` is more complete now: https://github.com/akicho8/string-inflection (note that there's also `string-inflection-camelize-lower` to change `hello_world` to `helloWorld`).

Answer (score 2):

For display purposes only, you can use this:

```
M-x glasses-mode
```

If you want a script which actually converts the text, I imagine you'd have to write some elisp.  That question is better asked on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this across a whole file quickly with just a query [replace regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html).

The search pattern is `\([a-z]+\)\([A-Z]\)\([a-z]+\)` and the replacement is `\1_\,(downcase \2)\3`.

The replacement pattern uses elisp right in the pattern.  This requires Emacs 22 or later.

In emacs documentation style:

```
M-C-% \([a-z]+\)\([A-Z]\)\([a-z]+\) RET \1_\,(downcase \2)\3
```